# How to pass multiple data from object to one p-columne PrimeNG

Tags: angular, primeng

I have:

```html
<p-dataTable [rows]="25" [paginator]="true" [pageLinks]="3" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[25,50,100]" [value]="searchFirm">

<p-column field="street" header="Address" [sortable]="true" [style]="{'overflow': 'hidden'}" [filter]="true" filterMatchMode="contains"></p-column>
```

My object:

```js
export interface Firm {
  postal_code: string;
  street: string;
  voivodeship: string;
  acronym: string;
  city: string;
  name: string;
  id: string;
}
```

Now i have only street in table (`field="street"`), but i want to be street, city and postal code. I tried to use ng-template but no results. Pls, help.

Comment: [value]="searchFirm" should be an array of your interface Firm

Comment: And then, how to pass multiple data to one p-column? (i should say one cell)

Comment: you cant instead you can use https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/colgroup

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that way.